# CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

Tags: objective-c

Can someone please explain what's exactly going on with this line of code starting at CGPoint. This comes from the `-(void)ccTouchesBegan`...

```
UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
```

In particular I'm not understanding the [touch view] part.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> In particular I'm not understanding the [touch view] part.

`[touch view]` is the UIView that user actually touched.

You might be helped further by reading my book's chapter on touches (at least the first few pages):

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html

Answer (score 1):

`[UITouch view]` documentation

> The value of the property is the view object in which the touch originally occurred. This object might not be the view the touch is currently in.

In other words, it's the innermost view at the touched position. However, if you tap and move the finger, the `view` doesn't change even if the touch is already in a different view.

Comment: So in [touch view], view is a property, not a method?

Comment: @user2252901 In Objective-C a property is name for 1 or 2 methods (getter or getter & setter), therefore you question doesn't make sense. `view` is a `readonly` property, in other words, it is a getter method.